# How to make image fill the slider

Tags: javascript, web, responsive, bxslider

I am developing a web app where I used *BXSlider* to show an image slide show on top of the page. The problem I have is the images does not fit into the slider. It shows white margins around the images. How to make the image fill the silder ?

**Edit:**

Here is my stylesheet:

```css
.bx-wrapper {
  position: relative;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  *zoom: 1;
}
.bx-wrapper img {
  max-width: 100%;
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
}
.bx-wrapper .bx-viewport {
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 0 #ccc;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 0 #ccc;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 #ccc;
  border: 0;
  left: -40px;
  background: #fff;
  /*fix other elements on the page moving (on Chrome)*/
  -webkit-transform: translatez(0);
  -moz-transform: translatez(0);
  -ms-transform: translatez(0);
  -o-transform: translatez(0);
  transform: translatez(0);
}
```

I've added `width: 100%` and `border: 0` options, but still the image does not fill the slider. It has some space left in the right end.

Comment: Could you please post your HTML/JS as it might be easier for debugging. I could suggest several solutions, but without the rest of your code I have no idea if they would be correct.

Comment: can you provide your code in fiddle, it will help to debug.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**UPDATE 2**

After reading comments I found out that changing bxslider.css isn't an option and that you'd prefer to override the offending style. I looked at the stylesheet and saw that the style you had posted was different than the original. Yours is:

```
.bx-wrapper .bx-viewport {
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 0 #ccc;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 0 #ccc;
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 #ccc;
    border:  0;
    left: -40px;
    background: #fff;
}
```

The original is:

```
.bx-wrapper {
   -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 5px #ccc;
   -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 5px #ccc;
    box-shadow: 0 0 5px #ccc;
    background: #fff;
}
```

> In short you targeted `.bx-viewport` instead of `.bx-wrapper`. So in Snippet 3, it is identical to Snippet 2 with some exceptions:

1. It's loaded with bxslider.css
2. There is an override targeting the correct selector:

   ```
    /* Override */

   .bx-wrapper.bx-wrapper {
     box-shadow: 0 0 0 transparent;
     border: 0 none transparent;
     background: none;
    }
   ```

`box-shadow` doesn't require prefixes see [caniuse](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-boxshadow). I doubled up on the class in order to increase specificity. If `!important` is like using a sledgehammer then double class is a ball peen hammer.

---

**UPDATE**

I reread your question and noticed you have the slider at the top of the page, so full screen isn't going to help in your particular situation, Snippet 2 demonstrates bxSlider edge style. Please review both Snippets in Full page mode.

> Everything from Snippet 1 applies with the exception of the following ruleset...

```
.bx-wrapper li {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  min-height: 200px;
  display: table;
}
```

> ...and if there any background images that have `background-size: cover`, it should be `background-size:contain`. In this demonstration slide 1 was altered as previously explained.

Basically, change `height: 100vh` to `height:auto` and add `min-height` which the value varies according to your layout but use an absolute value. Intrinsic and relative values don't workout very well with `min-height` under certain circumstances (e.g. absolute value: 200px, intrinsic value: 20vh, relative value: 20%)

---

> The following ruleset is the reason why you are having trouble:

```
 /* REMOVE THIS RULESET
.bx-wrapper .bx-viewport {
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 0 #ccc;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 0 #ccc;
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 #ccc;
    border:  0;
    left: -40px;
    background: #fff;
*/
```

> and do not use the bxslider.css stylesheet unless you remove that ruleset.

---

> Instead of `<img>` I used `background-image` on each `<li>` then used `background-size` to insure that every image touches the edges of the slider.

---

> The rest of the styles I added to perfect it's fullscreenness (is that a word?). Keyboard arrows are enabled, the controls and pager disabled. It will move with mouse drag, touch, and arrow keys. AFAIK, you can use any combination of options and it'll still run without any problems.

**SNIPPET 1 - Full Screen Edge**

```js
$('.bx').bxSlider({
  keyboardEnabled: true,
  pager: false,
  controls: false
});
```

```css
*,
*::after,
*::before {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0 none transparent;
  outline: 0 none transparent;
}
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
.bx-wrapper {
  position: relative;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow-y: hidden;
}
.bx-viewport {
  position: absolute;
  -webkit-transform: translatez(0);
  transform: translatez(0);
  left: 0;
}
.bx-wrapper li {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  display: table;
}
```

```html
<main class='bx-box'>

  <ul class='bx'>
    <li class='slide' style='background-image:url(http://imgh.us/transparent-map.png); background-size:cover;background-repeat:no-repeat;background-position:center;'>

    </li>
    <li class='slide' style='background-image:url(http://imgh.us/static.gif); background-size:cover;background-repeat:repeat;background-position:center;'>

    </li>
    <li class='slide' style='background-image:url(http://imgh.us/Lenna.png); background-size:contain;background-repeat:repeat;background-position:center;'>

    </li>
    <li class='slide' style='background-image:url(http://imgh.us/your_logo_here.jpg); background-size:cover;background-repeat:no-repeat;background-position:center;'>

    </li>
    <li class='slide' style='background-image:url(http://imgh.us/gir_zim.gif); background-size:contain;background-repeat:no-repeat;background-position:center;'>

    </li>

  </ul>

</main>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src='//cdn.jsdelivr.net/bxslider/4.2.5/jquery.bxslider.min.js'></script>
```

**SNIPPET 2 - Top of Viewport Edge**

```js
$('.bx').bxSlider({
  keyboardEnabled: true,
  pager: false,
  controls: false
});
```

```css
*,
*::after,
*::before {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0 none transparent;
  outline: 0 none transparent;
}
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
.bx-wrapper {
  position: relative;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow-y: hidden;
}
.bx-viewport {
  position: absolute;
  -webkit-transform: translatez(0);
  transform: translatez(0);
  left: 0;
}
.bx-wrapper li {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  min-height: 200px;
  display: table;
}
```

```html
<main class='bx-box'>

  <ul class='bx'>
    <li class='slide' style='background-image:url(http://imgh.us/transparent-map.png); background-size:contain;background-repeat:no-repeat;background-position:center;'>

    </li>
    <li class='slide' style='background-image:url(http://imgh.us/static.gif); background-size:cover;background-repeat:repeat;background-position:center;'>

    </li>
    <li class='slide' style='background-image:url(http://imgh.us/Lenna.png); background-size:contain;background-repeat:repeat;background-position:center;'>

    </li>
    <li class='slide' style='background-image:url(http://imgh.us/your_logo_here.jpg); background-size:cover;background-repeat:no-repeat;background-position:center;'>

    </li>
    <li class='slide' style='background-image:url(http://imgh.us/gir_zim.gif); background-size:contain;background-repeat:no-repeat;background-position:center;'>

    </li>

  </ul>

</main>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src='//cdn.jsdelivr.net/bxslider/4.2.5/jquery.bxslider.min.js'></script>
```

**SNIPPET 3**

```js
$('.bx').bxSlider({
  keyboardEnabled: true,
  pager: false,
  controls: false
});
```

```css
*,
*::after,
*::before {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0 none transparent;
  outline: 0 none transparent;
}
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
.bx-wrapper {
  position: relative;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow-y: hidden;
}
.bx-viewport {
  position: absolute;
  -webkit-transform: translatez(0);
  transform: translatez(0);
  left: 0;
}
.bx-wrapper li {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  min-height: 200px;
  display: table;
}
/* Override */

.bx-wrapper.bx-wrapper {
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 tramsparent;
  border: 0 none transparent;
  background: none;
}
```

```html
<link href='//cdn.jsdelivr.net/bxslider/4.2.5/jquery.bxslider.css' rel='stylesheet'>
<main class='bx-box'>

  <ul class='bx'>
    <li class='slide' style='background-image:url(http://imgh.us/transparent-map.png); background-size:contain;background-repeat:no-repeat;background-position:center;'>

    </li>
    <li class='slide' style='background-image:url(http://imgh.us/static.gif); background-size:cover;background-repeat:repeat;background-position:center;'>

    </li>
    <li class='slide' style='background-image:url(http://imgh.us/Lenna.png); background-size:contain;background-repeat:repeat;background-position:center;'>

    </li>
    <li class='slide' style='background-image:url(http://imgh.us/your_logo_here.jpg); background-size:cover;background-repeat:no-repeat;background-position:center;'>

    </li>
    <li class='slide' style='background-image:url(http://imgh.us/gir_zim.gif); background-size:contain;background-repeat:no-repeat;background-position:center;'>

    </li>

  </ul>

</main>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src='//cdn.jsdelivr.net/bxslider/4.2.5/jquery.bxslider.min.js'></script>
```

Comment: Your'e very welcome. I just updated again, I found exactly why your override didn't work in the first place. It would've worked but you were one off.

Comment: So I assume that the suggested edit to this was just your session expiring?

Comment: @StephenLeppik You are correct, sir. I usually have 2 tabs open and I believe I had cleared the cache before I opened the second one or something to that effect.

Answer (score 1):

change the jquery.bxslider.css file or override the css (.bx-wrapper img)

```
.bx-wrapper img{
   width : 100%;
}
```

Give it a try.

Its working with default css overriding. 
If you are linking any else css, this could be the reason. Please provide us with some code so we can help you better and faster.

Comment: Changing the `jquery.bxslider.css` is not a good option, as we can override it using our own css file.
`width: 100%` did not filled the image.

Comment: @ThisaruGuruge i know but i thought u might be keeping the same effect for the whole web slider.

Answer (score 1):

You have to override the default border on bx-viewport

```
.bx-wrapper .bx-viewport{
   border: 0;
}
```

This should remove the white margins around the images. You can just override this in your stylesheet instead of modifying jquery.bxslider.css.

Comment: This did not made the image fill the slider.

Comment: this wont fill the image inside the slider

Comment: @azs06 Yes. But in my case image does not fill the silder.

Comment: To make the image fill the slider you have to add `.bx-wrapper img{width:100%}` as mentioned by @Himanshu Bansal.